# Iterated Gateaux derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, gateaux-derivative

Let $F[h]$ be a generic functional of the function $h(x):{\mathbb{R}^d}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Consider the following definition of Gateaux derivative in direction  $g(x):{\mathbb{R}^d}\mapsto \mathbb{R}$

\begin{equation}
\tag{1}
\frac{\partial F[h]}{\partial g}\triangleq \left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\varepsilon}F[h+\varepsilon g]\right]_{\varepsilon=0}
\end{equation}

and the following definition for the second order derivative (still in direction $g(x)$)

\begin{equation}
\tag{2}
\frac{\partial^2 F[h]}{\partial g^2}\triangleq \left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}\varepsilon^2}F[h+\varepsilon g]\right]_{\varepsilon=0}
\end{equation}

given these defintions, I would like to prove (or disprove) the following relation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 F[h]}{\partial g^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial g}\left[\frac{\partial F[h]}{\partial g}\right]
\tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}

**My attempt**

Before starting, note that from $(1)$ follows immediately the simplified formula for the first order Gateaux derivative
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}
\frac{\partial F[h]}{\partial g}=\lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{F[h+\tau g]-F[h]}{\tau}
\end{equation}
Now, my strategy is to show that the RHS of $(\star)$ and the LHS of $(\star)$ are equal to a common expression. So, for the RHS we have from $(3)$ that
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial g}\left[\frac{\partial F[h]}{\partial g}\right]&=
\frac{\partial}{\partial g}\left[\lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{F[h+\tau g]-F[h]}{\tau}\right]\\
&=\lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{1}{\tau} \left\{ \frac{\partial F}{\partial g}[h+\tau g]-\frac{\partial F}{\partial g}[h]\right\}\\
&=\lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{1}{\tau} \left\{ \lim_{\sigma\to 0}\frac{F[(h+\sigma g)+\tau g]-F[h+\tau g]}{\sigma}-\frac{F[h+\sigma g]-F[h]}{\sigma}\right\}\\
&=\lim_{\tau,\sigma \to 0} \frac{F[h+(\sigma+\tau) g]-F[h+\tau g]-F[h+\sigma g]+F[h]}{\tau\,\sigma}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

For the LHS we have to compute $(2)$. In order to do it, note that
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}\varepsilon^2}F[h+\varepsilon g]&=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\varepsilon}\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\varepsilon}F[h+\varepsilon g]\right]\\
&=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\varepsilon}\left[\lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{F[h+(\varepsilon+\tau)g]-F[h+\varepsilon g]}{\tau}\right]\\
&=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\varepsilon}\left[\lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{F[h+\varepsilon g+\tau g]-F[h+\varepsilon g]}{\tau}\right]\\
&=\lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{1}{\tau}\left[\frac{\text{d}F}{\text{d}\varepsilon}[h+\varepsilon g+\tau g]-\frac{\text{d}F}{\text{d}\varepsilon}[h+\varepsilon g]\right]\\
&=\lim_{\tau \to 0} \frac{1}{\tau}\left[\lim_{\sigma \to 0} \frac{F[h+(\varepsilon+\sigma) g+\tau g]-F[h+\varepsilon g+\tau g]}{\sigma}-\frac{F[h+(\varepsilon+\sigma) g]-F[h+\varepsilon g]}{\sigma}\right]\\
&=\lim_{\tau,\sigma \to 0} \frac{F[h+(\varepsilon+\sigma) g+\tau g]-F[h+\varepsilon g+\tau g]-F[h+(\varepsilon+\sigma) g]+F[h+\varepsilon g]}{\tau \sigma}
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
Accordingly, the LHS is given by
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
 \frac{\partial^2 F[h]}{\partial g^2}&=\left[\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}\varepsilon^2}F[h+\varepsilon g]\right]_{\varepsilon=0}\\
&=\lim_{\tau,\sigma \to 0} \frac{F[h+\sigma g+\tau g]-F[h+\tau g]-F[h+\sigma g]+F[h]}{\tau \sigma}
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
which is the same as the RHS.

**Question**

I'm not sure if my proof is correct because I don't know if I have written correctly the limits involved in the definitions of the derivatives. So my question is the following: do you see any problem in my derivation of $(\star)$?

Comment: You would need to justify when $\lim_{\tau \to 0}\lim_{\sigma \to 0} = \lim_{\tau, \sigma \to 0}$ carefully. See Clairaut's theorem for a similar case. If you assume $F$ is $C^2$, then it is true.